# Please Provide a Search in Question-text only

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, search

Please provide a way to search only in Question-text.  I don't mean in one specific question, like the `inquestion:` search-option, but across all questions -- excluding the answers.

Say I'm trying to find ***questions*** about "Technology X"...

- The `title:` search-option helps, but often times the Question-Asker will only mention "Technology X" in the question body, not the title.
- Tag search helps but many questions are mistagged, or maybe the tag for "Technology X" wasn't available to the OP (or at all, yet).
- The `body:` search-option is no good, because it pulls in hundreds of questions where "Technology X" was mentioned as a solution (and may be) but the question is not particularly about "Technology X".   Or if "Technology X" has a name that is way overloaded -- EG: "Objective" or "Stylish", then it pulls in hundreds more junk results.

So please add a `questiontext:` search-option.   It Would really help out with (re)tagging questions and with searching for duplicates or related-answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been implemented (long ago, actually) with the `is:question` operator (which has a shorthand `is:q`). So the search query

```
is:q mistagged
```

([results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+mistagged)) will return your question, but not my answer, even though it does contain the word 'mistagged'.

Answer (score 2):

If you add `views:0` to a search string, it will reduce the search to only posts with at least 0 views. Consequently, only questions have views, so this is a general shortcut to reduce a search to only questions, not both questions and answers.

Thus, to search for text only in the question, you'd use `views:0 body:<term>`.

Comment: +1; That's a neat trick!  It's not intuitive, nor posted on the [search-options page](http://stackoverflow.com/search), so I shall struggle to remember it.  But, this does hint that it should be easy to implement a `questiontext:` feature. (^_^)